# Golang Alloc and HeapAlloc vs pprof large discrepancies

Tags: go, memory, profiling

I have a Go program that calculates large correlation matrices in memory. To do this I've set up a pipeline of 3 goroutines where the first reads in files, the second calculates the correlation matrix and the last stores the result to disk.

Problem is, when I run the program, the Go runtime allocates ~17GB of memory while a matrix only takes up ~2-3GB. Using `runtime.ReadMemStats` shows that the program is using ~17GB (and verified by using htop), but `pprof` only reports about ~2.3GB.

If I look at the mem stats after running one file through the pipeline:

```golang
var mem runtime.MemStats
runtime.ReadMemStats(&mem)
fmt.Printf("Total alloc: %d GB\n", mem.Alloc/1000/1000/1000)
```

This shows the total allocation of the program:

```sh
Total alloc: 17 GB
```

However, if I run `go tool pprof mem.prof` I get the following results:

```sh
(pprof) top5
Showing nodes accounting for 2.21GB, 100% of 2.21GB total
Showing top 5 nodes out of 9
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
    1.20GB 54.07% 54.07%     1.20GB 54.07%  dataset.(*Dataset).CalcCorrelationMatrix
    1.02GB 45.93%   100%     1.02GB 45.93%  bytes.makeSlice
         0     0%   100%     1.02GB 45.93%  bytes.(*Buffer).WriteByte
         0     0%   100%     1.02GB 45.93%  bytes.(*Buffer).grow
         0     0%   100%     1.02GB 45.93%  encoding/json.Indent
```

So I am wondering how I can go about to find out why the program allocates 17 GB, when it seems that the peak memory usage is only ~2.5GB? 
Is there a way to trace the memory usage throughout the program using pprof?

**EDIT**

I ran the program again with GODEBUG=gctrace=1 and got the following trace:

```
gc 1 @0.017s 0%: 0.005+0.55+0.003 ms clock, 0.022+0/0.47/0.11+0.012 ms cpu, 1227->1227->1226 MB, 1228 MB goal, 4 P
gc 2 @14.849s 0%: 0.003+1.7+0.004 ms clock, 0.015+0/1.6/0.11+0.018 ms cpu, 1227->1227->1227 MB, 2452 MB goal, 4 P
gc 3 @16.850s 0%: 0.006+60+0.003 ms clock, 0.027+0/0.46/59+0.015 ms cpu, 1876->1876->1712 MB, 2455 MB goal, 4 P
gc 4 @22.861s 0%: 0.005+238+0.003 ms clock, 0.021+0/0.46/237+0.015 ms cpu, 3657->3657->3171 MB, 3658 MB goal, 4 P
gc 5 @30.716s 0%: 0.005+476+0.004 ms clock, 0.022+0/0.44/476+0.017 ms cpu, 5764->5764->5116 MB, 6342 MB goal, 4 P
gc 6 @46.023s 0%: 0.005+949+0.004 ms clock, 0.020+0/0.47/949+0.017 ms cpu, 10302->10302->9005 MB, 10303 MB goal, 4 P
gc 7 @64.878s 0%: 0.006+382+0.004 ms clock, 0.024+0/0.46/382+0.019 ms cpu, 16548->16548->7728 MB, 18011 MB goal, 4 P
gc 8 @89.774s 0%: 0.86+2805+0.006 ms clock, 3.4+0/24/2784+0.025 ms cpu, 20208->20208->17088 MB, 20209 MB goal, 4 P
```

So it is quite obvious that the heap grows steadily through the program, but I am not able to pinpoint where. I've profiled memory usage using `pprof.WriteHeapProfile` after calling the memory intensive functions:

```
func memoryProfile(profpath string) {

    if _, err := os.Stat(profpath); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        os.Mkdir(profpath, os.ModePerm)
    }

    f, err := os.Create(path.Join(profpath, "mem.mprof"))
    fmt.Printf("Creating memory profile in %s", "data/profile/mem.mprof\n")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := pprof.WriteHeapProfile(f); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    f.Close()
}
```

Comment: The runtime isn't necessarily able to allocation only the minimum required memory. How are you determining the peak usage? What does the gctrace output show as required for the heap while the program is running?

Comment: Possibly related to recently solved issue [30333](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30333): "...a temporary spike in memory causes the Go runtime to grow the heap, but it takes a very long time (on the order of minutes) to return that unneeded memory back to the system...".

Comment: @JimB I am fine with the runtime allocating more memory than needed, but ~14 GB extra seems a bit excessive. I have used `pprof.WriteHeapProfile()` to trace memory usage, but as you can see it is not very helpful. Which leads me to believe that I am either not using it correctly, or I have misunderstood its capabilities.

Comment: @Gronnesby: that's why I mentioned `gctrace`, which will show the heap allocation in relation to the garbage collector goals. Also make sure you're using go1.12.5.

Comment: The go profile is a sampling profiler, so it's not an absolute measure, you use to compare thing relative to each other. You can increase the `MemProfileRate` and see if that helps narrow things down for you. You can also write benchmarks for the individual components, and use `-benchmem` to see where the allocations are happening.

Comment: Setting the `MemProfileRate=1` seems to work. There are now additional functions listed in the `pprof` profile that was previously omitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by [JimB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32880/jimb), the go profile is a sampling profiler and samples memory usage at certain intervals. In my case the sampling was not frequent enough to catch a function (JSON marshalling) that was using extensive amounts of memory.

Increasing the sample rate of the profiler by setting the environment variable

`$ export GODEBUG=memprofilerate=1`

Will update[`runtime.MemProfileRate`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/?source=post_page---------------------------#pkg-variables)and the profile now includes every allocated block.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution (as it was in my case) is that the binary was compiled with `-race`, which enables checking for race conditions.

The overhead for this is *huge* and will look like a massive memory leak if checking with `htop` or something similar, but won't show in any pprof output