# Why go heap profiler shows significantly less total memory than MemStats.HeapAlloc?

Tags: go, memory-leaks, pprof, heap-profiling

I'm trying to investigate a memory leak in our service. And for some reason, while `HeapAlloc` grows up to `3.7gb`, pprof heap profiler explains only `2.4gb`. What is that `1.3gb` space for?

I thought, that `HeapAlloc` memory is exactly what heap profiler should describe.

Comment: Hi Svetlana. Can you elaborate a bit on your service? How do you run it, on what platform, does it spawn child processes, use coroutines etc.

Comment: As I know, go usually pre-reserve memory for scaling later. Even with hello world program, It may pre-reserve 1GB of memory.

Comment: @AndreWildberg it's a usual web server, it runs in Kubernetes pod. It does use goroutines (I've also monitored goroutines count, and there are no goroutines leak), no, it does not spawn child processes.

Comment: @Minh, Yep, but as I understand, MemStats.HeapAlloc monitors the amount of memory, allocated for objects, and it does not include free slab slots, as HeapInuse does.

Comment: @Svetlana In that case, I can only think about sample rate of pprof. May be at the time pprof get sample, the memory was freed? You should try to increase the sample rate of pprof.

Comment: similar issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56150617/golang-alloc-and-heapalloc-vs-pprof-large-discrepancies